# Update existing elements causes multiple appending D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Mine svg has many node objects and from time to time I would like to update their content. But after I do updating, the group element of every node (which was already been added to the layout) has multiple copies of content in it.

So, obviously the problem is in multiple appending to the same element on `enter()` function, but how to prevent this kind of behavior?

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150583/d3-js-exit-remove-a-group-element-is-not-working), that it could be checked, if my `.nodes` element is empty, but this method is not suitable for my situation, because I have filled `.nodes` element already.

**Question:** So, may be it is better to delete all old content on `enter` and append again new one to each group element? How it could be done?

The code is quite the same as in link I provided, so feel free to see it, if you need to.

Comment: You don't need to remove everything before updating. See for example [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/).

Comment: You're going to have to provide some source code if you want us to help with your actual issue rather than just answer the question you ask at the end.

Comment: See Lars's answer. You need to update your data, not overwrite it.